# SQL - How to select master records that have no detail records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (Table1 - master table, Table2 - detail table). How can I select (view) only those records from master table that have no records in detail table? What SQL statement can I use for this? I'm using MS SQL Server 2012.

Edit: Table definition

Table1 - ID (PK)
Table2 - ID (PK), Table1ID (FK)

Comment: Do the records in the two tables share the same ID ?

Comment: Table1 - ID (PK) and Table2 [ID (PK), Table1ID (FK)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`NOT IN`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) Operator

```
SELECT *
    FROM   Table1
    WHERE  ID NOT IN(SELECT Table1ID
                           FROM   Table2 )
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` since it's clear, efficient and has no issues with nullable columns.

For example (`MasterID` is the PK/FK):

```
SELECT master.*
FROM dbo.Table1 master
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Table2 detail
    WHERE detail.MasterID = master.MasterID
)
```

But you have other options: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 1):

How about using an exclusive (left) outer join?

```
 SELECT 
       master.* 
 FROM 
       master LEFT OUTER JOIN details 
 ON    master.ID = details.masterID         
 WHERE details.ID IS NULL;
```

Have a look [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) for a more detailed description why this query is a solution to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using left joins in such cases:

```
select tp.*
from   table_parent tp
       left join table_child tc on tc.parent_id = tp.id
where  tc.parent_id is null
```

Answer (score -1):

this will help you greatly in answering your question:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

```
SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2);
```